# Server to Validate Credentials (Socket Programming)

Tags: c, string, sockets, multidimensional-array

First of all, I'm a beginner in c. This program simulates a server that a client connects to via telnet on port 8000 and give it a username and a password and the server validates them. I successfully get the username from the client, but I have some problem validating it. I need to compare the username with a the list of credentials, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code I've written so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char * credentialsList[7][2] = {{"Alice","abcdef"}, {"Bob","1234567"}, {"Cindy","qwerty"}, {"David","abababab"}, {"Eve", "cdefgh"}, {"Frank","7654321"}, {"George", "12341234"}};
    int serverSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int new_socket, i;
    char *message, client_message[10];
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    server.sin_family =  AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8000);
    bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    listen(serverSocket,2);
    int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    message = "Welcome! You Are Now Connected To The Server.\n\n";
    write(new_socket, message, strlen(message));
    message = "Please Enter A Valid Username: ";
    write(new_socket, message, strlen(message));
    recv(new_socket, client_message, 10, 0);
    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(credentialsList[i][0], client_message) == 0)
        {
            // TO DO
            puts("GOT YOU");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's not clear what does the received data look like. Does it have a null-terminator?

Comment: @ForceBru Code Edited!

Comment: I mean, could you please give an example of data received?

Comment: An example would be the username "Alice" @ForceBru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C programming a string will be terminated by a NULL character (ie;'\0' whose hex value is 0x00). So @juhist says to end the data received using a NULL character, here I'll simply clear the whole client_message[] array with NULL charatcer so that if we receive , lets suppose 8 character the 9th character will be terminated by the NULL character to ensure that's a string

```
memset(client_message,0x00,sizeof(client_message));
recv(new_socket, client_message, 10, 0);
    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(credentialsList[i][0], client_message) == 0)
        {
            // TO DO
            puts("GOT YOU");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah. but still the value received does not match with any value in the 2d array. For example, the username "Alice".

Comment: add puts(client_message); after the recv() function , is that giving you the expected message on the screen (this just prints the data received)

Comment: Also the length of the client_message has to be max 9 ( eventhough you've declared 10 , one element should have to be reserved for NULL character 0x00, otherwise try increasing the client_message array size like client_message[50] )

Comment: I've updated the post , might be because of that char array declaration

Comment: removing the `*` from `char * credentialsList` would generate an error.

Comment: also if we take a simple statement like `int x= strcmp(client_message,"Alice"); printf("%i", x);` it won't give us 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73484/discussion-between-sorcrer-and-user3490561).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are implicitly assuming that the received data has a '\0' terminator. This isn't typically the case for network protocols. Furthermore, how do you know if the full username is received? Now it just reads how many bytes are available in a TCP segment, and you shouldn't make your program reliant on the TCP segmentation details. Furthermore, you're ignoring the return value of the recv() system call which may read 10 bytes or may read fewer bytes.

Instead of recv(), I recommend creating a function recvall() which calls the function recv() in a loop, handling partial reads correctly by re-recv()'ing for more data.

One option would be to transfer the length of the username as a 32-bit binary integer in network byte order, and then use recvall() to receive the 4-byte length of the username, and then using recvall() for as many bytes as you want to read. The program that writes the data obviously needs changes too, to first write the length of the username as a 32-bit binary integer in network byte order.

There are other possible options, too. For example, you could use '\n' (i.e. the newline) to terminate the username but that would require calling recv() in a loop using a 1-byte buffer which is very inefficient or alternatively using your own buffering solution on top of recv(). So, my recommendation is to send the length of the username as a 32-bit integer in network byte order; that is far simpler.

In general, you should check the return values of all system calls. In addition to ignoring the return values of recv() system calls, you're also ignoring the return value of write() system calls. This is bad practice.

For consistency, I suggest using either recv() and send() or write() and read(), not mixed functions like recv() and write().

I also heavily recomend adding blank lines to your code to structure it. It's hard to read now with no blank lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. But I can't really follow along what you're saying. I'm a beginner in c and socket programming. So If you could please elaborate more on what needs to be changed and what needed to be added in the code, I would really appreciate that.